# Adding an int in a method and displaying it in the main

Tags: java, methods

```
public class Race {

public static void main(String[] args) {
int maxSpeed = Car.getMaxSpeedForAll();
    int raceLength = 1000;

    Car mario = new Car(30, "Mario");
    Car luigi = new Car(30, "Luigi");

    while(mario.getLocation() < raceLength || luigi.getLocation() < raceLength){
            mario.randomSpeedChange();
            luigi.randomSpeedChange();
            if (mario.getLocation() > luigi.getLocation()){
                System.out.println(mario + " is in first place at " + mario.getLocation() + "!");
            }
            if (luigi.getLocation() > mario.getLocation()){
                System.out.println(luigi + " is in first place at " + mario.getLocation() + "!");
            }
            if (mario.getLocation() == luigi.getLocation()){
                System.out.println(mario + luigi + "are neck and neck! Who will pull ahead and take the lead?!");
            }
        }
    }
}


import java.util.Random;

public class Car {
    private int speed;
    private String carName;
    private int location = 0;
    Random r = new Random();
    private int rand;

    private static int maxSpeedForAll = 120;
    private static int minSpeedForAll = 0;

    public Car(int speed, String name) {
        this.speed = speed;
        this.carName = name;
    }

    public int getLocation(){
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(int location, int speed){
        this.location += speed;
    }

    public static int getMaxSpeedForAll(){
        return maxSpeedForAll;
    }

    public static void setMaxSpeedForAll(int maxSpeedForAll){
        Car.maxSpeedForAll = maxSpeedForAll;
    }

    public static int getMinSpeedForAll(){
        return minSpeedForAll;
    }

    public static void setMinSpeedForAll(int minSpeedForAll){
        Car.minSpeedForAll = minSpeedForAll;
    }

    public int getSpeed(){
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(int speed){
        if(speed <= maxSpeedForAll){
            this.speed = speed;
        } else {
            this.speed = maxSpeedForAll;
        }
        if(speed < minSpeedForAll){
            this.speed = minSpeedForAll;
        }
    }

    public String getName(){
        return carName;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.carName = name;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String result;
        result = carName;
        return result;
    }

    public void accelerate(int rand){
        if (rand > 0){
            speed += 10;
        }   
    }

    public void decelerate(int rand){
        if (rand < 0){ 
            speed += -10;
        }
    }

    public void randomSpeedChange(){
        setRand(r.nextInt(10 - -10) + -10);
    }

    public int getRand() {
        return rand;
    }

    public void setRand(int rand) {
        this.rand = rand;
    }
}
```

So I am currently doing an assignment where I need to race two cars in a set race length. To determine the current position of the cars in the race, I have to add the value of the cars' positions to the value of the cars' speed, and that value has to be displayed in the main. Simple enough I suppose, but the speed of the cars are altered randomly every time the race loops on an interval of -10 to 10. I have been working on different solutions to this for a few days and I am no closer to actually making this code work how it is meant to work, and if someone could give me some pointers on what the heck I am doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it.

In summary, I am attempting to:
1) Add an integer (location) to an integer (speed) and return it to the main.
2) Change one integer (speed) by adding/subtracting randomly between -10 and 10 during every loop before adding it to the other integer (location).

I apologize in advance if this was answered somewhere already - I have searched this site high and low for a similar problem with a solution and couldn't really find any that was the same situation as my problem.

Answer (score 2):

A few things for a possible result:

1. After the value of `rand` is determined, you should perform a check to see whether or not to call `accelerate` or `decelerate`. These methods should *only* modify the value of `speed`.
2. `accelerate` and `decelerate` should call `setSpeed` using the modified value of `speed` as an argument.
3. After the speed is set, `setLocation` should be called. If the `location` parameter in the `setLocation` method will not be used, it does not need to be listed as a formal parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This line does not compile:

```
System.out.println(mario + luigi + "are neck and neck! Who will pull ahead and take the lead?!");
```

You need to use your `toString()` method in order to make this work. I'd also recommend adding the word "and" as well as spaces because it currently outputs "MarioLuigiare neck and neck! (etc.)"

The way your code is currently written; `mario.speed` and `luigi.speed` are never modified, keeping both at a constant speed throughout the race. You need to either call the `accelerate()` and `decelerate()` methods or include code in `randomSpeedChange()` to modify their speed

You also never change their location, keeping them perpetually at the starting line. You should call the `setLocation()` method for each after changing their speed to fix this.

I would also recommend modifying the `decelerate()` method to ensure `speed` never falls below zero, unless you intend for them to be able to go backwards (the first time I ran it after fixing the issues I mentioned above, they ended up with huge negative numbers for `location`).

Here are the changes I made to the code (besides adding `toString()` to the line mentioned at the top of my answer):

The `randomSpeedChange()` method:

```
public void randomSpeedChange(){
    setRand(r.nextInt(10 - -10) + -10);
    accelerate(rand);
    decelerate(rand);
}
```

The `while` loop in the main method:

```
while(mario.getLocation() < raceLength || luigi.getLocation() < raceLength){
        mario.randomSpeedChange();
        mario.setLocation();
        luigi.randomSpeedChange();
        luigi.setLocation();
        //all the if statements here
}
```

The `setLocation()` method:

```
public void setLocation(){
    location += speed;
}
```

(This method worked fine, but the parameters were unnecessary.)

The `decelerate()` method:

```
public void decelerate(int rand){
    if ((rand < 0) && (speed >= 10)){ 
        speed += -10;
    }
}
```

This ensures that `speed` is at least `10` before reducing it, to make sure that it never falls below 0.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't change speed and location in the loop block. I guess this maybe what you need:

Main class:

```
public class Race {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int maxSpeed = Car.getMaxSpeedForAll();
        int raceLength = 1000;

        Car mario = new Car(30, "Mario");
        Car luigi = new Car(30, "Luigi");

        while(mario.getLocation() < raceLength || luigi.getLocation() < raceLength){
            if (mario.getLocation() > luigi.getLocation()){
                System.out.println(mario + " is in first place at " + mario.getLocation() + "!");
            }
            if (luigi.getLocation() > mario.getLocation()){
                System.out.println(luigi + " is in first place at " + mario.getLocation() + "!");
            }
            if (mario.getLocation() == luigi.getLocation()){
                System.out.println(mario.getName() + luigi.getName() + "are neck and neck! Who will pull ahead and take the lead?!");
            }

            //change the speed randomly
            mario.randomSpeedChange();
            luigi.randomSpeedChange();
            //change the location according to speed
            mario.setLocation(mario.getLocation(), mario.getSpeed());
            luigi.setLocation(luigi.getLocation(), luigi.getSpeed());
        }
    }
}
```

Car class:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Car {
    private int speed;
    private String carName;
    private int location = 0;
    Random r = new Random();
    private int rand;

    private static int maxSpeedForAll = 120;
    private static int minSpeedForAll = 0;

    public Car(int speed, String name) {
        this.speed = speed;
        this.carName = name;
    }

    public int getLocation(){
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(int location, int speed){
        this.location += speed;
    }

    public static int getMaxSpeedForAll(){
        return maxSpeedForAll;
    }

    public static void setMaxSpeedForAll(int maxSpeedForAll){
        Car.maxSpeedForAll = maxSpeedForAll;
    }

    public static int getMinSpeedForAll(){
        return minSpeedForAll;
    }

    public static void setMinSpeedForAll(int minSpeedForAll){
        Car.minSpeedForAll = minSpeedForAll;
    }

    public int getSpeed(){
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(int speed){
        if(speed <= maxSpeedForAll){
            this.speed = speed;
        } else {
            this.speed = maxSpeedForAll;
        }
        if(speed < minSpeedForAll){
            this.speed = minSpeedForAll;
        }
    }

    public String getName(){
        return carName;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.carName = name;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String result;
        result = carName;
        return result;
    }

    public void accelerate(int rand){
        if (rand > 0){
            speed += 10;
        }
    }

    public void decelerate(int rand){
        if (rand < 0){
            speed += -10;
        }
    }

    public void changeSpeed(int rand) {
        if (rand > 0){
            speed += 10;
        }
        if (rand < 0){
            speed += -10;
        }
    }

    public void randomSpeedChange(){
        setRand(r.nextInt(10 - -10) + -10);
        changeSpeed(rand);
    }

    public int getRand() {
        return rand;
    }

    public void setRand(int rand) {
        this.rand = rand;
    }
}
```